# AVL Tree in ML- Rotate left, Warning: match nonexhaustive

Tags: sml, avl-tree

I am implementing an AVL tree in SML:

Here are my datatypes:

```
datatype 'a AVLTree = Nil | Br of ((int*('a))*('a AVLTree)*('a AVLTree));
datatype Balance = RR | LR | LL | RL;
exception NotFound;
exception NullValue
```

I am now writing the function Rotate- Left, and I wrote it as follows:

```
fun rotate_left Nil = Nil
     |rotate_left (Br(x,A,Br(y,B,C))) = (Br(y,Br(x,A,B),C));
```

I am getting from the interpreter:

> Warning: match nonexhaustive

How do I fix this with the current datatypes I have?
I tried using wildcards but with no success..

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting from the interpreter:
>
> ```
> Warning: match nonexhaustive
> ```
>
> How do I fix this with the current datatypes I have? *[...]*

Perhaps this warning should not be avoided. You can after all not rotate all trees.

The left rotation would look like this:

```
  A              B
 / \            / \
…   B     ~>   A   C
   / \        / \ / \
  …   C      …   …   …
     / \
    …   …
```

---

Given an AVL tree type that does not keep track of the height,

```
datatype 'a AVLTree = Nil | Br of 'a * 'a AVLTree * 'a AVLTree
```

*(the parentheses are not necessary)* your version of `rotate_left` is correct. I've rewritten it below and renamed the left and right sub-branches. One point is that B's left sub-branch becomes A's new right sub-branch.

```
fun rotate_left (Br (a, leftA, Br (b, leftB, rightB))) =
                 Br (b, Br (a, leftA, rightB), rightB)
```

This is a partial function, and the patterns it fails to match are:

- `Nil` – but a left-rotation of an empty tree isn't well-defined.
- `Br (a, leftA, Nil)` – but the following left-rotation also isn't well-defined:

  ```
    A             ?
   / \           / \
  …   Nil   ~>  A   …
               / \
              …   ?
  ```

If you were to try and perform a left-rotation of one of those trees, there would not be a meaningful result. Having the `Warning: match nonexhaustive` is not satisfying either. You could instead raise a meaningful exception, e.g.

```
fun rotate_left (Br (a, leftA, Br (b, leftB, rightB))) =
                 Br (b, Br (a, leftA, rightB), rightB)
  | rotate_left _ = raise Fail "Invalid left-rotation"
```

---

Now, you haven't really explained why there's an extra *int* in your datatype definition. Maybe this is the pre-computed height of the tree? That'd be neat (you could encode that meaning using a type alias), since then your invariance check becomes cheaper. In that case, a left-rotation would need to update the heights:

```
type height = int
datatype 'a AVLTree = Nil | Br of height * 'a * 'a AVLTree * 'a AVLTree
```

According to the top drawing, A's new height is `max(height(leftA), height(leftB)) + 1` and B's new height `max(height(new A), height(rightB))`. Extending the `rotate_left` function for this:

```
fun height Nil = 0
  | height (Br (h, _, _, _)) = h

fun rotate_left (Br (ha, a, leftA, Br (hb, b, leftB, rightB))) =
    let val ha' = Int.max (height leftA, height leftB) + 1
        val hb' = Int.max (ha', height rightB) + 1
    in Br (hb', b, Br (ha', a, leftA, rightB), rightB) end
  | rotate_left _ = raise Fail "Invalid left-rotation"
```

---

**Edit:** It occurs to me that the extra *int* is in a nested tuple and so probably turns the tree into a mapping from some integer to some *'a*. In that case, disregard the optimization of keeping the height in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

You function is not defined for values with the shape `Br(x, A, NIL)`.

What should happen in this case?

```
fun rotate_left Nil = Nil
  | rotate_left (Br(x,A,Br(y,B,C))) = (Br(y,Br(x,A,B),C))
  | rotate_left (Br(x, A, Nil)) = (* ??? *);
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this functions a little bit and this is what I got that works:

```
 fun RL node =
  case node of Br(x,A,Br(y,B,C)) => (Br(y,Br(x,A,B),C))
                             | _ => node;
```